# Problem syncing custom timer to system clock

Tags: java, android, timer

I have a custom timer that I'm keeping synced to the system clock.  It's working fine for one minute intervals, but I also need it to sync to 36 second intervals (for updating fields when the user wants times displayed in decimal hours).  Inside the `Runnable` I recalculate the adjustment (accurate enough for my needs) for the next minute, but can't find a way to conveniently deal with the different offsets needed for 36 seconds.

**EDIT**

```
    private static class DecimalTimer extends TimerClass {

        final int[] seconds = new int[101];
        private boolean keepRunning = true;
        private Runnable mRunnable;

        @Override
        void kill() {
            keepRunning = false;
        }

        @Override
        Runnable getRunnable() {
            return mRunnable;
        }

        DecimalTimer() {
            final int[] counter = new int[1];
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 3600; i += 36, j++) {
                seconds[j] = i;
            }
            mRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (!keepRunning)
                        return;
                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int hourSeconds = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 60 + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

                    for (counter[0] = 0; counter[0] < 100; counter[0]++) {
                        if (seconds[counter[0]] > hourSeconds) {
                            c.add(Calendar.SECOND, seconds[counter[0]]);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    long adjustedDelay = (c.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis()) % 36000;

                    for (IntervalTimer listener : sListeners) {
                        listener.updateTime();
                    }
                    sHandler.postDelayed(this, adjustedDelay);
                }
            };


        }
    }
```

This edit fires every 36 seconds, but I need to get it to sync to 36 seconds on the clock (ie: 12:00:00, then 12:00:36 .. 12:01:12 .. 12:01:48)

Answer (score 0):

Overthinking things as usual, this is what I came up with.  It's accurate enough for what I need, but if anyone has an improvement for accuracy (It's a little off when it executes with 900ms or more) it'd be appreciated.

```
        DecimalTimer() {
            mRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (!keepRunning)
                        return;

                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    do {
                        c.add(Calendar.SECOND, 36);
                    } while (c.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis());
                    long adjustedDelay = (c.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis()) % 36000;

                    for (IntervalTimer listener : sListeners) {
                        listener.updateTime();
                    }
                    sHandler.postDelayed(this, adjustedDelay);
                }
            };
        }
```